# Facebook API - how to retrieve "is_verified" pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, restfb

I'm using Java for searching public page info in Facebook.
I chose for now to use the Facebook4J but this is not a must.
I succeeded to search for pages named "Some Name" and I would like to read the is_verified property of the page to make sure this is the official page I'm looking for and not a faked one. 
There is no isVerified() method on Page object and I do not how to run a FQL query using the search API.

This FQL runs well in Facebook simulator:

```
select page_id, name, is_verified, is_community_page  
from page 
where name='Tom Cruise' and is_verified=1
```

The Java code I'm having right now is this:

```
ResponseList<Page> pages = facebook.searchPages(personName);
```

I tried copy-paste the FQL into the search as parameter, as the method signature is

```
ResponseList<Page> searchPages(String query) throws FacebookException;
```

but I get no results...

I also cannot loop on all 'Tom Cruise' pages and ask whether they are verified or not because, as I mentioned before, there is no 'isVerified()' method on Page.

I'll appreciate any Java solution, even if it means that I should drop Facebook4J for another platform.

Answer (score 0):

The is_verfied page field is added with RestFB version 1.10.0.